# Convert XML to Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml, xmldom

I have xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
<form>
    <input name="id">1</input>
    <input name="name">Steven Law</input>
    <input name="position">Sales Manager</input>
</form>
<form>
    <input name="id">2</input>
    <input name="name">Martin Wow</input>
    <input name="position">Production</input>
</form>
<form>
    <input name="id">3</input>
    <input name="name">Mike Pan</input>
    <input name="position">Office boy</input>
</form>
</table>
```

I tried to get element value.I don't know how to get element value for each field. So far I'm try like this, it is just get an attribute value:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("data.xml");

$input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach($input as $inputs){
  $name= $inputs->getAttribute('name');
  //$value = $field->name('id');
  echo "$name =<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id =
name =
position =
id =
name =
position =
id =
name =
position =
```

What I want is will be output `id=1 name=Steven Law ... id=3 name=mike pan position=office boy`. After that, from output I can make to an array.

Oh one more, please tell me about different XMLDOM and SimpleXML. I don't know must choose what. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the value can be done with `DOMElement::nodeValue`:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("data.xml");

$input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach($input as $inputs){
  $name= $inputs->getAttribute('name');

  $value = $inputs->nodeValue; //reading the value
  echo "$name = $value<br>"; 
}
```

**Notice**

To test this, the XML example has to be corrected: In the first block the `<input>` elements are closed with `</field>`. This has to be changed to `</input>`.

You asked for an array. It depends on how you need the data in your application. 
Here are two possibilities, which should give you an idea to go on:

**a) Creating an array (the easy way)**

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("data.xml");

$array=array(); //init

$input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach($input as $inputs){
  $name= $inputs->getAttribute('name');
  $value = $inputs->nodeValue;

  //adding a value
  $array[]=array(
    'name' => $name,
    'value' => $value,
    );
}
// as an example, just print it
print_r($array);
```

You'll get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => id
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [value] => Steven Law
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => position
            [value] => Sales Manager
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => id
            [value] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [value] => Martin Wow
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => position
            [value] => Production
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => id
            [value] => 3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [value] => Mike Pan
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => position
            [value] => Office boy
        )
)
```

**b) Creating an array (more convenient to use later on)**

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("data.xml");

//init
$array=array();
//get all form tags
$forms=$dom->getElementsByTagName('form');
foreach($forms as $form) {
    //get all input-Tags from this form
    $input = $form->getElementsByTagName('input');

    //create an empty element
    $element=array();
    //walk through the input elements of the current form element
    foreach($input as $inputs){
      $name= $inputs->getAttribute('name');
      $value = $inputs->nodeValue;
      //add the data to the element
      $element[$name]=$value;
    }
    //add the element to your array
    $array[]=$element;
}
// as an example, just print it
print_r($array);
```

Here you'll walk through your `<form>` elements first. Then, in every form you read the `<input>` elements. So, you'll get an entry for every form block containing the inputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Steven Law
            [position] => Sales Manager
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Martin Wow
            [position] => Production
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Mike Pan
            [position] => Office boy
        )

)
```

Comment: sorry it's my mistake for closed with `field` . thank you I wil try soon as possible

Comment: please help me too. to make an array. and tell me about dom or simplexml should must I'm use. Update you answer please @akrys

Comment: `simplexml` is easier to code, `domxml` is a little bit more tolerant to smaller XML errors. It depends on which API you'd like to use.

Comment: @akrys Regarding error tolerance, you can always use DOM's HTML parsing mode, and then use the `simplexml_import_dom` to convert the object to SimpleXML (without any extra processing - they use the same internal representation). That way you get the best of both (if you like SimpleXML's simplified API style).

Comment: That's great hint! The next time, I don't have to refector all my code. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try simplehtmldom it is easier to use than xmldom or simplexml. You should be able to use css selectors to find the data you need.

Comment: You're not tell me the code to get element value. The poin question is about code. What simplehtmldom? I'm not hear that until now

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm